# Value for $\cos (\frac {nx}{2})$ and $\sin (\frac {nx}{2})$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I calculate the values of  $\cos (\frac {nx}{2})$ and $\sin (\frac {nx}{2})$ for $n=4k, 4k-1, 4k-2, 4k-3$. $n,k \in \mathbb {N}$?

Comment: Hem, $4k, 4k-1, 4k-2, 4k-3$ are all naturals, no ?

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{inx/2}=\left(e^{ix/2}\right)^n=\left(\cos\frac x2+i\sin\frac x2\right)^n$$ which you can expand by the Binomial theorem, and separate the real and imaginary parts.

Then from

$$\cos2t=2\cos^2t-1=1-2\sin^2t$$

you get

$$\cos\frac x2=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}2},\\
\sin\frac x2=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}2}.
$$

Remains to discuss the signs.

Note that for even $n$, there is no need to use the half-angles.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how this answers my question?